# Change Password Structure without effecting current users

Tags: php, authentication

I am looking for some help or advice on best practices to update my password system. I built a log in system awhile ago using php (before I really knew what I was doing) and all it does is encrypt passwords using sha1 Which I know is not secure or good to use.

So basically on successful login all it does is

```
$password = sha1($password1)
```

I would like to use a different method I have been using lately which is using a CRYPT_BLOWFISH function like so:

```
 function generateHash($password_1){
    if(defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH){
         //echo "WE HAVE CRYPT BLOWFISH YAYA";
         $salt = '$2y$11$'. substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
         return crypt($password_1, $salt);
    }//End If
}//End Function generateHash*/
```

On Registration I encrypt the password:
    $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
    //Hash the Password
    $password = generateHash($password_1);

Then on Login I use

```
$hashed_password = crypt($password_1, $entered_password)
if($hashed_password != $enter_password){
    $error['password'] = 'The password or username you entered is incorrect.';
}else{
    'Your Good to Go!'
}
```

I have many users and would like to make the change seamlessly or at least very minimal effect to them. Is this even possible to do without them noticing a change? Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You could check how long the password is, sha1 should be exactly 40 characters long, if it is 40 characters long then use the old method and direct them to the change password page, else use the new method.

Comment: is your table has a inserted date column field ?

Comment: Yes I have a automatic timestamp column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the idea Cvetomir. So what I did was was create a new column in the table called encrypted_password and basically, all new registrations will be encrypted using CRYPT_BLOWIFSH.

So basically my solution (Not sure how elegant it is but it works) Looks at each password. If the password entered match the SHA1 password then grab that posted password and encrypt it into the new format and add it to the database.

Once the encrypt password column is updated then I will remove the old password columns Anyway happy to hear thoughts/suggestion to make it better but for now it works, Lots of trial and error in this one.

```
if(!$errors && $username == $teacher_row['username']){
    if($_POST['password1'] != ''){
        $old_password = filter_var($_POST['password1']);
        $old_password = sha1($old_password);
       //If the old SHA1 Password does not match anything in the database then try and match it with our new method 
       if($old_password != $teacher_row['password1']){
            //New Password will be the $_POST Password          
            $new_password = $_POST['password1'];
            //Grab the new column
            $user_password = $teacher_row['encrypted_password'];

            //Uncrypt the password to see if they match
            $hashed_password = crypt($new_password, $user_password);
            //If it doesn't match throw an error            
            if($hashed_password != $user_password){
                $errors['username'] = 'The username or password you entered is incorrect.';
            }//If Hashed Password != User password
            else{
                if($hashed_password == $user_password){
                    //The New Password does match and gain your session
                    session_regenerate_id();
                    //Create our session on session_id and hash it as well
                    $session_id = generateHash($id)                     
                    $_SESSION['DHL'] = $session_id;
                    $_SESSION['TIMEOUT'] = time();
                    $_SESSION['TEACHER_ID'] = $teacher_username;
                    session_write_close();
                }
            }else{              
                $encrypted_password = generateHash($_POST['password1']);
                //Build our query
                $sql = ("UPDATE members_teachers SET encrypted_password = ? WHERE username = ?") or die(htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
                //Prepare our query
                $stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die ('database connection() failed: '. htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));

                //Prepare our query
                $stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die($db_connection->error);

                //Can not proceed if we can not prepare the query
                if(false===$stmt){ die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
                }   
                //Bind the fields and there paramters to our query in our testing variable $next_step
                $next_step = $stmt->bind_param('ss', $new_password, $teacher_username);
                //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding
                if($false===$next_step){ die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
                }   
                //Place the Execute into a variable and test if it executed or not
                $next_step = $stmt->execute();
                //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding 
                if(false===$next_step){ die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));    
                }
            }
        }
        else{ //The Old Passwords Must Match

            $password = generateHash($_POST['password1']);

            //$errors['username'] = 'Password Correct '.$_POST['password1'].' and '.$password.'';

            //Build our query
            $sql = ("UPDATE members_teachers SET encrypted_password = ? WHERE username = ?") or die(htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
            //Prepare our query
            $stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die ('database connection() failed: '. htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));

            //Prepare our query
            $stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die($db_connection->error);

            //Can not proceed if we can not prepare the query
            if(false===$stmt){die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
            }   
            //Bind the fields and there paramters to our query in our testing variable $next_step
            $next_step = $stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $teacher_username);
            //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding
            if($false===$next_step){
            die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
                        }   
            //Place the Execute into a variable and test if it executed or not
            $next_step = $stmt->execute();
            //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding 
            if(false===$next_step){die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error)); 
                }

            //The New Hashed password does match We are good
            session_regenerate_id();
            //Create our session on session_id
            $session_id=generateHash($dhl_id);                              
            $_SESSION['DHL'] = $session_id;
            $_SESSION['TIMEOUT'] = time();
            $_SESSION['TEACHER_ID'] = $teacher_username;
            session_write_close();

        }//End the old Passwords do match

    }//If password is not Blank 
    else{
        $errors['username'] = 'You must enter a password';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new column in user table ex. password, **newPassword**
When user login you can hash password with new algorithm and save it in column newPassword.
After few days rename column newPassword as password